Flutter iOS app with Extension failing to archive: "Archive Missing Bundle Identifier"
I'm facing an issue while trying to archive my Flutter iOS app. I've recently added a Device Activity Report extension for ScreenTime API integration to a feature branch. The archive process fails with the error "Archive Missing Bundle Identifier." In contrast, the main branch, which does not include this extension, archives successfully. Also one of the key changes is the Build Phase order that i had to change to make the device activity report work as a platform view in flutter (pasted image of the current build phase order).
Build Phase Screenshot
Error Message
Archive Missing Bundle Identifier
Domain: IDEArchivedApplicationErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Archive content at path /Users/**/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2024-09-23/alpha release 4 23-09-24, 11.51 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Runner.app is missing a bundle identifier.

Project Details

Project Type: Flutter with iOS native extension
Xcode Version: 15.4 (22622) (Build 15F31d)
macOS Version: 14.2.1 (Build 23C71)
Main App Target: Runner
Extension Target: Device Activity Report

Observations

The issue occurs only during the archiving process; building for a device works without errors.
The addition of the Device Activity Report extension is the only difference between the main and feature branches.

Questions

What could be causing the "Archive Missing Bundle Identifier" error specifically on the feature branch after adding the Device Activity Report extension?
How can I ensure the extension is properly linked and embedded in the main app for successful archiving?
Are there any specific configurations or steps required for Flutter projects with ExtensionKit extensions that might be causing this issue?

What I've Tried

Verified that bundle identifiers for both the main app and the extension are correctly set in project settings and Info.plist files.
Ensured the extension has the required family control permissions and entitlements.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times.
Ran flutter clean and flutter pub get.
Checked that the extension target is visible and not showing any errors in the project navigator.
Confirmed that the "Embed ExtensionKit Extensions" build phase is present in the Runner target.


you open your project from if bundle identifier properly added in project navigator or not then see the signing of you team whether your team is properly signed or not if you add some extension you have to give that bundle identifier too if you are having notification extension you have give that distinct identifier
